# How can I connect mysql with Arduino using GSMshield

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

How can I include `mysql.h` library in IDE of Arduino to connect Arduino to mysql database by using GSM shield?

Comment: You add the line: `#include <mysql.h>` ? Your question isn't clear. I'm going to close this question. Feel free to edit it with new information. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Arduino is too small to run `libmysqlclient` directly. There are few other solutions:

1. You can expose your database using REST API and call that.
2. Change hardware platform to Raspberry Pi - it runs full Linux system
3. Run your app on PC and call Arduino using some RPC library

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on GPRS data connection on your GSM shield and perform HTTP GET or POST request to the web page script (for example PHP script), which in turn will access the MySQL database (write or read DB records). It is easier than implementing REST API.